# Разгадать что делает программа

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int n, int k) {
    if (k > n / 2) { 
        cout << n << " "; 
        return; 
    }
    if (n % k == 0) { 
        cout << k << " "; 
        f(n / k, k); 
    }
    else f(n, ++k);
}
int main() {
    int N = 19;
    f(125 + N,2);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Вывод:
2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Есть программа с рекурсивной функцией, она делает что-то, возможно находит какие то определенные элементы, или считает что-то по какойто формуле. Надо разгадать загадку, надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: выводит все множители. 2*2*2*2*3*3 = N. Решение так себе...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо :)))